# What is the best way to create Binance Smart Chain (BSC) transactions via geth without a full node?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, light-clients, project-fork, binance-smart-chain

I currently run geth to create and query the ethereum blockchain for transactions in light mode. I don't have a eth full node running. I tried running the same similar setup for Binance Smart Chain in light mode, but running into issues. Is there another proposed way to go about creating transactions on BSC via geth in light mode? Or even another service that can do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you consume your node api? Curl ? Web3/ethers? What are the issues you are encountering ?

Comment: My users have eth private keys and they are essentially the same thing on BSC. I've been just submitting eth transactions using curl sending it to geth in light mode.

Comment: Do you only need to broadcast already signed transactions? Or do you need to create the transaction, sign it and broadcast it? How do you currently sign transaction for your users?

Answer (score 3):

It look like BSC light node have issues since last update (see this GitHub issue for instance https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/issues/452 )

As an alternative, Binance has free endpoint (https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html) and there are a few third-party providers (Quicknode, Ankr, Moralis) offering BSC nodes (sometimes at a cost).